# How were the arrows in the new "About Page 2.0" created?

Tags: discussion, design

Just out of curiosity, regarding those damn hot new ["About Page 2.0" pages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/) and the arrow images that were used there:

[image]

My question is:

**Which tool was used to create those arrows?**

(The reason that I'm asking is that I recently was in the need to have some arrows, too, and didn't find any reasonable utility to create them)

Comment: They look vector-based.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I do think so. I ended up using Visio to draw my arrows, but the SO arrows look way better!

Comment: Inkscape is your friend.  http://inkscape.org/  (Unless you have money.  Then Adobe is your friend.)

Comment: Thanks, @squillman - I've downloaded and even looked at some tutorials be seem to be unable to find any slightly high-level function that supports arrows. Can you give me a further hint where to look at?